# Python 'is' vs JavaScript ===

Tags: javascript, python

The Python use of 'is' seems to be similar to JavaScript '===' but not quite.

Here they talk about exact instances:
http://www.learnpython.org/en/Conditions

here (for JS) they talk about "equal AND the same type."
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

SO can you have two different instances of (say) a string of "Bob" and have them not return true when compared using 'is'? Or is it infact the same as ===?

I am guessing this is related to strict vs non-strict typed languages. . . .

Comment: This doesn't have to do with types, `is` tests object identity (i. e. whether two names (or other references) refer to the same object (residing at the same address in memory)), whereas `==` checks if the objects compare equal. (`1 == 1.0`).

Comment: Related: [`is` operator behaves differently when comparing strings with spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16756699/is-operator-behaves-differently-when-comparing-strings-with-spaces)

Comment: @TimPietzcker It does for the JS side AFAIK. User-defined objects can't overload `==` or `===`, and JavaScript's predefined notion of equality *is* object  identity, i.e. for objects (as opposed to primitives), JavaScript's `===` does act like Python's `is`.

Comment: @delnan: As far as I know, `===` does not check object identity, it just checks if they are of equal value and of equal type. But they may reside at different memory addresses.

Comment: @TimPietzcker [Nope](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21488340/395760). It's actually quite hard to define (deep) value equality for arbitrary object graphs correctly, it's a potential performance hog, and "equal type" is also a fuzzy concept (is it the prototype? do we take inheritance into account? is it the set of members? do the types of the members influence the "type"?). Edit: Note that in JS, things like numbers and strings are not objects. I explicitly restricted myself to objects (user-defined ones, even, though this is probably redundant).

Comment: @delnan: But for example item 5. in the linked docs suggests that strings don't have to be the same object, just compare equal (plus there are many strange cases like comparisons with `Null` or `undefined` always returning `True`. See also Sean Viera's answer below - there seems to be a need for an `is`-like operator in JavaScript. (My usage of `object` in the above comment was meant to refer to an object in the Python sense, not a JavaScript `object`. Sorry for the confusion)

Comment: @TimPietzcker I edited the last comment just now. I'm only talking about objects. Strings are not objects as far as JS is concerned.

Comment: in JS, ({valueOf: function(){return 5}}) == 5 is true but ({valueOf: function(){return 5}}) === 5 is false...

Comment: @TimPietzcker @delnan Please check my answer. I have included the actual algorithm used by JavaScript engines to evaluate `===`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Python Part

> SO can you have two different instances of (say) a string of "Bob" and
>   have them not return true when compared using 'is'? Or is it infact
>   the same as ===?

```
a = "Bob"
b = "{}".format("Bob")
print a, b
print a is b, a == b
```

**Output**

```
Bob Bob
False True
```

**Note:** In most of the Python implementations, [compile time Strings are interned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15541556/1903116).

Another example,

```
print 3 is 2+1
print 300 is 200+100
```

**Output**

```
True
False
```

This is because, small ints (-5 to 256) in Python are cached internally. So, whenever they are used in the programs, the cached integers are used. So, `is` will return `True` for them. But if we choose bigger numbers, like in the second example, (`300 is 200+100`) it is not True, because they are NOT cached.

**Conclusion:**

`is` will return `True` only when the objects being compared are the same object, which means they point to the same location in memory. (It solely depends on the python implementation to cache/intern objects. In that case, `is` will return `True`)

**Rule of thumb:**

NEVER use `is` operator to check if two objects have the same value.

---

## JavaScript Part

Other part of your question is about === operator. Lets see how that operator works.

Quoting from ECMA 5.1 Specs, [The Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6) is defined like this

> 1. If Type(x) is different from Type(y), return false.
> 2. If Type(x) is Undefined, return true.
> 3. If Type(x) is Null, return true.
> 4. If Type(x) is Number, then
>
>    1. If x is NaN, return false.
>    2. If y is NaN, return false.
>    3. If x is the same Number value as y, return true.
>    4. If x is +0 and y is −0, return true.
>    5. If x is −0 and y is +0, return true.
>    6. Return false.
> 5. If Type(x) is String, then return true if x and y are exactly the
>      same sequence of characters (same length and same characters in
>      corresponding positions); otherwise, return false.
> 6. If Type(x) is Boolean, return true if x and y are both true or both
>      false; otherwise, return false.
> 7. Return true if x and y refer to the same object. Otherwise, return
>      false.

## Final Conclusion

We can **NOT** compare Python's `is` operator and JavaScript's `===` operator, because Python's `is` operator does only the last item in the Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm.

```
7. Return true if x and y refer to the same object. Otherwise, return false.
```

Comment: The "rule of thumb" is actually the whole definition of `is`. And that's not the part that needs a rule pf thumb ;-)

Comment: In Python 3 your example gives True True as the result as compared to Python 2.7.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> a = "Hello, World!!!"
>>> b = "Hello, World!!!"
>>> a is b
False
```

However note that:

```
>>> a = "Bob"
>>> b = "Bob"
>>> a is b
True
```

In this case it condition was `True` because the compiler is free to intern string literals, and thus reuse the same object, and it does do that with small strings. However there is no guarantee as to when this happens of if this happens at all and the behaviour changes between versions and implementations.

---

A realiable `False` output should be:

```
>>> a = 'Hello, World!!!!'[:-1]
>>> b = 'Hello, World!!!!'[:-1]
>>> a is b
False
```

Or anything that actually *computes* the strings.

Comment: Also note that it's the compiler that actually interns the literals.

Comment: "the compiler is free to intern string literals" ??  Pls explain?

Comment: @RClaven What do you mean?

Answer (score 5):

Completely different.

```
>>> a = 'foo'
>>> b = 'bar'
>>> a + b is 'foobar'
False
>>> 1000 + 1 is 1001
False
```

Comment: The insidious part is that there are many naive tests which *do* output `True`. No answer on the topic is complete without debunking those.

Answer (score 5):

Python's `is` keyword compares references (and so is about identity) while [`===` does a minimal amount of coercion](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6) (and is therefore concerned with equality, at least in the case of primitives) so they are different.

As I understand it, things that are concerned with identity are concerned with uniqueness from the runtime's point of view (do these two variables point to the same address in memory) while equality is concerned with the uniqueness of the *contents* of the variables (are these two variables equivalent, regardless of where they are placed in memory relative to each other).

Comment: I'm surprised by that discussion (link please?) as the differences only show in "primitive"/non-Object types, which are special anyway and don't appear to have an identity as such. Sure, there are boxed equivalents and those can probably be constructed implicitly, but since this would create separate wrapper objects for both arguments that makes it a long-winded way of not considering any primitives equal to any other primitives. Am I missing something?

Comment: @delnan - true, it does only affect primitives, but sometimes you reference semantics for variables that might hold a primitives like `NaN` or `0`. Compare `===` with [`SameValue`](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-samevalue) - `NaN` is `NaN` but it does not equal `NaN`, while `-0` is not `+0` but they are equal.  Does that make sense (it's very late / early for me here, so I might be talking through my hat).