# javascript double equal comparing when create object using function constructor

Tags: javascript

why it is giving false ?

As double equal compare only values so it should return true OR is it comparing references (address value) ?

```
var a = new Number(3);
var b =new Number(3);

a == b ; // false 
a === b ; // false
```

As below returns true : (result as expected )

```
var a = new Number(3);
var b = 3;

a == b ; // true 
a === b; // false
```

Comment: it's just object vs primitive. every `new` generates an unique object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object and primitive type equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488340/object-and-primitive-type-equality)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704971/why-are-two-identical-objects-not-equal-to-each-other

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more of a type coercion question. As such you have to understand the rules and order in which objects and non-objects are handled.

```
var a = new Number(3);
var b =new Number(3);

a == b ; // false 
a === b ; // false
```

In your case your using the **new** keyword causing you to wrap the values in an object. **var a** and **var b** are two new/different objects. Objects in Javascript are unique. So **==** and **===** will only be True if you are comparing the same instance of the same object. (so a reference to that object).

The reason that this works:

```
var a = new Number(3);
var b = 3;

a == b ; // true 
a === b; // false
```

is because of the rules that govern the implicit type coercion:

> If Type(x) is either String or Number and Type(y) is Object, return
> the result of the comparison x == ToPrimitive(y).
>
> If Type(x) is Object
> and Type(y) is either String or Number, return the result of the
> comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.

So **var a** is first converted to a primitive value and then compared resulting in a true value.

For an in depth explanation: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20&%20grammar/ch4.md

Answer (score 0):

When you create the numbers like that:

```
var a = new Number(3);
var b =new Number(3);
```

You are creating unique objects.
If you type this into your console

```
typeof(a)
```

You will see

```
"object"
```

As the response. The same applies to the `b` variable.
Therefore they are not equal to each other.

But when you do this:

var x = 1;
var y = 2;

and check the `typeof` x and y you will see `"number"` as the response.

Here is some extra reading for you [Number in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

I hope it all makes sense now.